# Node Express Google OAuth across LAN

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, google-api, google-authentication

I have been working through a book called MEAN Web Development Amos Q. Haviv. I am trying to get an Google user authentication across the LAN network to the Node Express server on my machine.

So I have localhost:3000 and using http://localhost:3000/oauth/google/callback will return to my machine upon return from Google. However if I want to do something like 192.168.1.21:3000/oauth/google/callback or stefcomp:3000/oauth/google/callback, it just ends up an error.

As I am trying to run a socket chat script across the LAN, I am trying to chat with my machine from another machine on the network, but I am having the problem, and the user needs to be authorised for it to work.

Comment: What's the error? Have you updated the Google API credentials to allow connections from `192.168.1.21:3000`?

Comment: If I attempt to set the callback domain to be http://192.168.1.21:3000/oauth/google/callback in the Authorised redirect URIs section for the Googles API setup for my OAuth, doesn't accept ip addresses. so that doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, it seems you cant use an IP address as a callback.

Comment: You could try pointing a fake domain (stefcomp.com) to the IP address in your local host file and setting that as the redirect URL.

Comment: ok creating a proxy machine setting of stefcomp.com to my ipaddress in /etc/hosts on my machine and another I am testing with, and setting the value on Google server, does allow me to log in as require. For facebook however, trying to add stefcomp.com to their server isn't allowed, probably as it isn't a real webserver. I haven't tried Twitter yet. Anyway got it working through Google is a big step forward, and adequate for me testing logged in users for my socket chat script, thanks

Comment: You're welcome! Those tools aren't design to work on a LAN so you might want to use a publicly accessible server with a real domain name.